# Searching org-mode files with spotlight

Tags: org-mode, osx

On my mac (OSX) I have many org-mode files with filenames ending in “.org”.

Whenever I do a search with Spotlight that should show one of these org files as best result I experience the following problems:

- The best org file often doesn’t appear on the results. Almost all the times, if there is the backup file (the “tilde” file ending with a `~`), it’s displayed but not the original org file.
- If spotlight decides to show the org file, it tends to be shown at the end of the list in the "Other" category.

If I do the same kind of research on files ending with `txt` spotlight does exactly what is supposed to do, the files pops on top of the results list.

Do you know a solution to this problem?

Is it possible to instruct spotlight to handle `*.org` files like `*.txt` (or other text format) files?